# Magento2 extend a class from SalesRule module

Tags: magento2.2, class, extend

I'm using magento 2.2 and I'm trying to extend a class, more exactly this one: \Magento\SalesRule\Model\Utility

And I'm facing an error:

```
Declaration of MagePal\CouponCodeExtraValidation\Model\SalesRule\ExtraValidation::canProcessRule(Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule $rule, Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address $address) should be compatible with Magento\SalesRule\Model\Utility::canProcessRule($rule, $address) in /Applications/magento-2.2.1-1/apps/magento/htdocs/app/code/MagePal/CouponCodeExtraValidation/Model/SalesRule/ExtraValidation.php on line 0
```

This is how my class looks like:

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace MagePal\CouponCodeExtraValidation\Model\SalesRule;

class ExtraValidation extends \Magento\SalesRule\Model\Utility
{
    public function canProcessRule(
        \Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule $rule, 
        \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address $address
    ){
        parent::canProcessRule($rule, $address);
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should define your method like this:

```
public function canProcessRule($rule, $address)
{
    parent::canProcessRule($rule, $address);
}
```

to make it compatible with the parent method.

Comment: thanks! it's ok now.
could you explain why sometimes I need to include that path before the variable and sometimes not?

Comment: @Cosmin That's purely a php question. If you have a class and you are defining a new class which does not define by its parent class, then you can type hint as you done here. But if you are redefining a method which already exists in the parent class, then you should define it exactly like in the parent class.